# Django 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blog/wsgi' when deploying to Elastic Beanstalk, as well as 'Error while connecting to Upstream'

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, upstream

I am trying to deploy a static Django website to Elastic Beanstalk via the UI 'upload your code' and not the EB CLI. I have created a zip file of all of my contents and have tried uploading it a million times, only to be met with the errors 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blog/wsgi' when deploying to Elastic Beanstalk, as well as 'Error while connecting to Upstream'. I think it is an error with the 'django.config' file in my .ebextensions folder. The contents of the 'django.config' file is: `option_settings: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python: WSGIPath: blog/wsgi:application`. The contents of my 'wsgi.py' file is `import os from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'blog.blog.settings') application = get_wsgi_application()`. I have attached a screenshot of [my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9lSy.jpg) as well. I can attach any other files if necessary. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when deploying to Amazon Linux 2 machine due to incompatibility of versions. I fixed it by changing the django.config file:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: ebdjango.wsgi
```

Credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62078670)